# Find the mass of a cone with proportional density using triple integral in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the mass of a cone given the following statement:

> In a straight, circular cone with height $h > 0$ and base radius $R > 0$ the density is proportional to the distance to the base area and equal to 2 at the tip of the cone. Find the cone's mass.

It seems easiest to use cylindrical coordinates. This is what I have tried:

Starting with the simpler limits, we have $0 \leq z \leq h$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$. For $r$ we can use the proportionality of a cone, looking at a side section, to get that $r = \frac{Rz}{h}$. This gives us the limit $0 \leq r \leq \frac{Rz}{h}$. For the density function, I interpret the problem as density being in linear proportion to $z$, in other words we have some density function $\rho(z) = kz$ with $\rho(h) = 2$. This should mean that $k = \frac{2}{h}$ if I'm not mistaken, and the function we want to integrate is $\frac{2z}{h}$.

Calculating the triple integral:

$m = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^h \int_0^{\frac{Rz}{h}} \frac{2z}{h} r\,dr\,dz\,d \theta =
\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^h \frac{R^2}{h^3} z^3 dz\,d \theta = 
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{R^2 h}{4} d \theta = 
\frac{1}{2} R^2 h \pi$

Does this look right?

Comment: You don't need a triple integral. Take cross-sections of the cone along the $z$-axis with thickness $dz$, find the mass of the cross-section as a function of $z$, and integrate from $z = 0$ to $h$.

Comment: Wouldn't that give the same result? Then I get the circle area $\pi r^2$ times $dz$ and the density function $\frac{2z}{h}$ which gives the integral $\int_0^h \frac{2z}{h} \frac{R^2 z^2}{h^3} dz = \frac{1}{2} R^2 h \pi$. But maybe just that was your point, that it's simpler :)

Comment: Yes, it is a good way of checking that your result is correct.